# Digits by Twitter and sms sender name/title

Tags: android, ios, twitter, twitter-fabric, twitter-digits

I am writting Android and iOS apps that use Digits by Twitter (https://get.digits.com/)

I have everything set up & working, but I would like to change sender title for sms that is sent to my clients when they register to my application.

Right now I managed to change application name in fabric.io panel, so SMS message is something like:

```
Confirmation code: XXXXXX. Enter this in YYYYY. (Digits by Twitter)
```

which is alright, but sender is still "Twitter".

Is there any way to change sender name to my application name (or anything else)?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here - do you mean the (Digits by Twitter) part? For the app's title, it can take up to 24 hours to take effect.

Comment: No, this part is fine. The thing i Would like to change is Sender title/name

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. Currently that's not possible, but good to know you'd like to see it.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Did'nt get your answer. Please let me know if (Digits by Twitter) could be removed or replaced and how.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Twitter should really consider removing that, many of our beta testers are confused by the sender name. It is better that it is changed by some random numbers. This forced us to move to Facebook's Account Kit, I prefer Twitter Digits ease of use, but still. The sender name could have a bad impact on the app

Comment: @MikeBonnell It should at least say, for APPNAME. Instead of for "your app" inside the sms content

Comment: The current SMS I received from adding Digits as a secondary login on Fabric was: "Enter code: xxxxxx into Fabric.io (Digits by Twitter)" When testing on an app, I got: "Enter code: xxxxxx into AppName (Digits by Twitter)" which I believe aligns with your desired approach.

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing this out there: as per the official answer found here:

https://twittercommunity.com/t/change-sms-title-and-remove-sms-text-digits-by-twitter/73827/2

You can *not* remove the `(Digits by Twitter)` part.

(This restriction alone has prevented us from using Digits in any of our apps. There's *no way* we're advertising Twitter in our confirmation messages, and ended up rolling our own system with Twilio as the SMS sender.)

Including official response below:

> You can change your application's name within the SMS as described
>   here:
>   https://docs.fabric.io/android/digits/sign-in-with-phone-number.html#configure-sms-confirmation-message
>
> The (Digits by Twitter) text cannot be removed.
>
> -Mike (Twitter Staff)